# Parse date embedded in other Text in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to parse date imbedded in some arbitrary text as follows

```
"hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011"
```

I know the pattern of the date (below), however I'm not sure how to parse it from the text string above. How do I do it?

```
String format = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date);
```

Comment: is this `hello world, good Day ` fixed ?

Comment: is the date always at the end of the string?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: no the string in the begining is not fixed

Comment: @gotomanners: yes the date is at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateFormat class!

Assuming you know what index the date is in the text,

```
String text = "hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011";
String dateText = text.substring(22);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Date date = df.parse(dateText);
```

The parse method should be able to construct a date object from the string if it is well formatted.

Here is the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

## EDIT

Knowing that the date is ***ALWAYS*** at the end of the string and that the date portion is always 28 characters long(?) ... you could cut out the end of the string and parse it to a date.

```
String text = "hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011";
String dateText = text.substring(text.length()-28); //28 is the date portion
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Date date = df.parse(dateText);
```

Comment: I get the feeling that the crux of the question is how to calculate the `22` (i.e. to distinguish between "date characters" and "non-date characters", and ignore the latter).

Comment: -1: parse is not a static method, and DateFormat is abstract; therefore, it can't work like this

Comment: apologies for the incorrect static method...typing in a hurry...it has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract the date from the expression. In this case:

```
([Mon|Thu|{rest of days}] [Jan|Feb|{rest of months} .... \d\d\d\d)
```

The parenthese () defines a group that can be retrieved with getGroup().

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position in the input string where the date starts, you can do something like this:

```
String input = "hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011";
String format = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(input, new ParsePosition("hello world, good Day ".length()));
```

If you don't know the position, you could use a regular expression to find the date in your format.

Comment: no I don't know the position, I was hoping to avoid regular expression to find the date

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround:

```
    String date = "hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011";
    date = date.replaceAll("^(?:.*)(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Sunday)", "$1");
    System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't bullet proof, but it should server you well. It will match a date anywhere in any String that "looks like" a date:

```
    String input = "hello world, good Day Thu Mar 03 07:13:56 GMT 2011 foo bar";
    String regex = "(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d [A-Z]{3} [12]\\d\\d\\d";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.find())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't find a date");
    String datestr = matcher.group();
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(datestr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force method that absolutely works:

```
public static Date parseDate(String input)
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 29; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return format.parse(input.substring(i, i + 29));
        }
        catch (ParseException ignore) {}
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

It just scans along the string trying every start position until it parses a date